# Own Shuffle Method Doesn't Work in Java

Tags: java, shuffle

I have created simple shuffle method everyting seems okay but there is a problem which i can't find.

Here is my Code Below:

```
public static <E> void shuffle(List<? extends E> list) {
    List<E> temp = new ArrayList<>();

    while (list.size() != 0) {
        E val = list.remove((int) (Math.random() * list.size()));
        temp.add(val);
        System.out.println(val);
    }
    System.out.println(temp);

    list = temp;
}
```

This is the test case:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    arr.add(1);
    arr.add(2);
    arr.add(3);
    arr.add(4);
    arr.add(5);
    arr.add(6);
    System.out.println(arr);

    shuffle(arr);

    System.out.println("-->" + arr);
```

The problem is last print out method shows that arr is empty  **--> [] It Should be something like that [4,3,1,2,6,5]** 
Problem could be this line but i did not understand why ?

```
 --> list = temp;
```

Comment: `list = temp` does not modify the original list, it just assigns the value of the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's this line:

```
list = temp;
```

All that does is copy the `temp` reference to the `list` reference.  Now, both `list` and `temp` refer to your local list originally referred to by `temp`.

You'll want to add the contents of `temp` back to `list` instead.

```
list.addAll(temp);
```

Answer (score 2):

`list = temp` just assigns a new value (the contents of `temp`) to the local variable named `list` - it does not change the object that `list` originally pointed to.

If you want to achieve such functionality, you could just re-add all the items in `temp` to `list` (after the `while` loop concludes, so you know it's empty):

```
list.addAll(temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

The shuffle method receives a copy of a reference to your list. When you do `list = temp;` you're telling that reference to point to `temp`.

So you basically empty the list that is passed to the method and then you lose access to it.